# Migrate pinnacle cart customers data to magento1.x version

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, pinnacle-cart

I came back on stackoverflow after long time.I really need a help in migrating the pinnacle cart to magento1.x.I am migrating the customer data but I want customer can login in magento site with same credentials without reset the password.

Is it possible that customer can use the same credentials of pinnacle cart to Magento after migration.

any quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: its also related with a programming .let me know if you have answer of this question

Comment: Can you please show how this is related to programming? I can't see anything about programming in the question.

Comment: It does'nt mean that if there is no code in question then its not related to programming

Comment: That I agree with. But it must explicitly have something to do with programming for it to be about programming. The site help specifically says that a question must be about "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". So the question must be **"unique to software development"**. Your question could simply be about getting the right extension or setting the configuration. It's not explicitly about programming.